# Русская буква 'x' в названиях флеш-баннеров

Tags: flash

Всем привет. Столкнулся с такой непоняткой: в названиях флеш-баннеров не распознается английская буква 'x'.

Примеры:

http://radio-toys.com/uploads/images/1389608139_banner_1000100_farmer.swf  - работает

http://radio-toys.com/uploads/images/1387462649_banner_AGP_Media_660х100.swf - не работает

Локально файлы открываются и отлично работают. Картинки, которые содержат английские буквы 'x', тоже открываются без проблем

Что это может быть? Ума не приложу...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://radio-toys.com/uploads/images/1387462620_banner_AGP_Media_660%f5100.swf
```

Это оно? У вас не английская буква **x** была скорее всего, а × (&times)
Из-за этого, вероятно, при загрузке название файла исказилось.

*p.s. проверяйте названия файлов перед загрузкой. У вас в папке **/uploads/images/** черт-те что творится.*

Comment: хорошо. а почему когда я через файлзиллу ставлю английскую 'x', оно по порежнему не работает? А когда ставлю любую другую - a, q, w, r - то прекрасно работает? фигня какая-то....

Comment: На момент просмотра папки /uploads/images/ я не обнаружил проблемного файла (файла с таким именем не было), поэтому ничего сказать по этому поводу не могу.

Comment: может там какой-нибудь mod_rewrite стоит?

Comment: Нет, выяснилась в чем проблема. Автор набирал Х на русском языке. Вот тот файл:  

    http://radio-toys.com/uploads/images/1387462649_banner_AGP_Media_660%23U0445100.swf
U0445 === х (русская)

Comment: @VenZell, я уже тоже разобрался. Это оказалось клиенты предоставили названия баннеров с русской х. Все, проблема решена. Всем спасибо.

Comment: @VenZell, 

> p.s. проверяйте названия файлов перед загрузкой. У вас в папке /uploads/images/ черт-те что творится.

забыли сделать фильтрацию русских букв перед загрузкой. бывает